# schroot only works as root

Tags: linux, chroot, centos7

I recently changed my OS from openSUSE to CentOS. A part of that transition was migrating my chroot jails and schroot configuration.
That transition does however not seem to be "plug and play". I used to be able to use schroot as my user "richard", but on CentOS only the root user is able to use schroot.

This is higly inconvenient since operations that were quick and easy now require password input. Is there a configuration that I can change to allow the richard user to use schroot?

### Example

```
$ schroot -c kanos date
E: kanos-247a7d6f-8a4e-4ac2-8d5a-99ce7d66b8a3: Failed to lock chroot:/var/lib/schroot/session/kanos-247a7d6f-8a4e-4ac2-8d5a-99ce7d66b8a3: Failed to write session file: Permission denied

$ sudo schroot -c kanos date
Fri Apr 10 11:43:53 GMT 2015
```

*Note: I have attempted to change the permissions on **/var/lib/schroot/session/** and **/var/lib/schroot/mount/**, to give the richard user access. Schroot did not like that and complained that only root should have access.*

```
$ schroot -c kanos date
E: 10mount: mount: only root can use "--bind" option
E: 10mount: /etc/schroot/setup.d/10mount: line 52: /var/lock/schroot/umount: Permission denied
E: kanos-92acb0de-f663-4bd0-a6b6-9bbe9771b454: Chroot setup failed: stage=setup-start
```

### System info

```
CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 (Core)
schroot-1.6.5-5.el7.x86_64
```

### Configuration

```
[kanos]
description=kanos build server jail
type=directory
directory=/var/chroot/kanos
users=richard
groups=richard
root-users=root
root-groups=root
personality=linux32
preserve-environment=true
```

Comment: what is your SELinux set to? What does <code>sestatus</code> return?

Comment: $ sestatus 
SELinux status:                 enabled  
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux  
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux  
Loaded policy name:             targeted  
Current mode:                   enforcing  
Mode from config file:          enforcing  
Policy MLS status:              enabled  
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed  
Max kernel policy version:      28

Comment: Sorry about the clustered response. I cant seem to get this thing to add line breaks.

Comment: in other words selinux is enabled. Which is a good thing. However you may want to drop it into "permissive" mode to test whether that can give you your desired functionality back. If it does - I can provide answer to question on how to tune SELinux to get functionality back

Comment: Changing to permissive mode did not affect the outcome.

Comment: $ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Max kernel policy version:      28

Comment: I was getting nowhere with this issue. Gave up on CentOS, and switched my OS to Fedora. schroot is working fine there.

Answer (score 2):

I met the same issue and found the solution. You need to set the setuid root to the schroot executable file. The step is shown below.

1. `cd /usr/bin`
2. `sudo chmod 4755 schroot`
3. enjoy it.